# Qual a melhor prática para limpar um html?

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

Estou trabalhando com javascript a pouco tempo, e vejo as pessoas comentando sempre que o innerHTML é uma pratica ruim.

Concordo que não fica um código muito bonito escrever htmls pelo próprio js, mas tenho muito costume de usar o innerHTML para limpar uma tabela ou lista.

A duvida é, se não for utilizar o innerHTML para limpar listas, preciso percorrer todos os nós que desejo apagar com um while, e ir apagando um a um.
Alem do código ficar maior, queria saber em questão de performance qual é mais aconselhável, os prós e contras de ambas.
E se existe alguma outra maneira.

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar Jquery desta maneira: `$('#suaLista li').text('')`. Em questão de performance o navegador não irá nem sentir dor para nenhuma das maneiras :)

Comment: alguma solução para js puro ?